# How to Save a Checkbox State in jStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, jstorage

I have asked a similar question earlier where i asked whether i could save a checkbox in localStorage but i have just recently found out about a part of jQuery called jStorage - and was wondering if i could use that to save a pair of checkboxes i have created in my web app?

The HTML code is as follows (for the checkboxes);

```
<li style = 'color: #FFFFFF;'>Notifications<span class = 'toggle'><input type = 'checkbox' class = 'toggle' name = 'notifications' id = 'notifications' /></span></li>
<li style = 'color: #FFFFFF;'>Preview<span class = 'toggle'><input type = 'checkbox' class = 'toggle' name = 'preview' id = 'preview' checked = "true" /></span></li>
```

And i have no JavaScript code for saving the states of these checkboxes yet - however in my .js file i have two functions - *saveSettings* and *loadSettings*. if there is a way to save the state of the checkbox and then load in back onto the page when the user revisists the web app, then please tell me, but i can also create a new function if necessary, just please tell me which option you are telling me about :)

**EDIT**

My saveSettings function is (so far) coded as such;

```
  function saveSettings(){ 

localStorage.name = $('#name').val();   
localStorage.email = $('#email').val(); 
localStorage.telephone = $('#telephone').val(); 

localStorage.other = $('#other').val(); 

jQT.goBack(); 

return false;  

 }
```

and my loadSettings function is coded as such;

```
 function loadSettings() {

$('#name').val(localStorage.name);
$('#email').val(localStorage.email);
$('#telephone').val(localStorage.telephone);

$('#other').val(localStorage.other);

 }
```

**END OF EDIT**

Thanks a lot in advance - any help is greatly appreciated xxx

Comment: ...ok...do you know how to answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

In your saveSettings function, add:

```
$.jStorage.set("notifications",$('#notifications').attr('checked'));
$.jStorage.set("preview",$('#preview').attr('checked'));
```

In your loadSettings function, add:

```
    $.jStorage.get("notifications")?$('#notifications').attr('checked',$.jStorage.get("notifications")):false;
    $.jStorage.get("preview")?$('#preview').attr('checked',$.jStorage.get("preview")):true;
```

As i dont have your loadSettings () and saveSettings() code functions, i cannot help you more.

And please not plugin specification:

> > > jStorage makes use of HTML5 local storage where available and userData behavior in Internet Explorer older versions.
> > >
> > > If the browser doesn't support data caching, then no exceptions are raised - jStorage can still be used by the script but nothing is
> > >       actually stored.

Comment: hang on i think i coded your answer into my js file wrong - the function bit is separate from the functions i have already created am i right? and i'm confused as to where the jStorage.set stuff goes - in saveSettings or loadSettings??

Comment: thanks but the page still won't work - but i've edited my answer to give you the code for my two functions. there's more to the js file, so if you think you need to see it here's a link to the dropbox page (the js file i am referring you to is called 'save.js'); https://www.dropbox.com/home#!/home/Public/Project

Comment: no nothing comes up at all - it's just a grey screen. index.html is the main page if you want to test it (in the dropbox link) x

Comment: is there a way to code the jStorage stuff inside one function instead of inside the two different ones? it worked for the selection list thing x

Comment: Ya, you could. For testing your code, i dont have dropbox account and i dont want to open one. Try to put your code on fiddle. One last thing, set your DOC type to: <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Comment: eh? doc type? is that instead of <html> i put what you suggested? and i don't think you need a dropbox account to view it - but here's the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/pu5hd/

Comment: Declaration of DOC type is (should be!) the first line of your html page code if not a php one. The code you provide is quite unreadable. Ive tested with a simple example, jStorage works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/pu5hd/2/

Comment: ok...but i've never done the doctype thing before and my programs have worked fine. also, is there a tag to close the doctype or does it just stay open?

Comment: This DOC type is to specify HTML5 as jStorage use it, see there http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp for W3C specification. I edited my answer as ive made an inversion between loadSettings code and saveSettings code

Comment: ok thanks. i'll check the HTML code and see if there's a problem there, cause it still won't work. thanks a lot for your help

Comment: hay i got my program working, but the settings button broke when i added your code...is there a way to put the save and retieve code into one function in JavaScript instead of across two? that might work better

Answer (score 0):

Just a little simplier solution :

to save

```
$.jsStorage.set('milk', $('.milk').prop('checked'));
```

to retrieve :

```
$('.milk').prop('checked',$.jsStorage.get('milk')==='true');
```

your checkbox being

```
<input type="checkbox" class="milk" name="option1" value="Milk">
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer - but it breaks my settings button so i can't access the page :S are you sure you put the code into your answer right? (no offense) x

Comment: I kind of made a guess of how it would look like using jQuery jsStorage. My code work using localstorage though : replace $.jsStorage with localStorage, set by setItem, and get by getItem, and you should get your behavior on browsers supporting localStorage. Take a look at the doc to make a working port. If you want more helpp, post the error message.